# The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.-- Upgrading Drupal from 8.9 to 9.3.5

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I am upgrading my drupal project from 8.9 to 9.3.5 but after the upgrade while hitting website one error occur i.e

> **The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.**

I followed the steps mentioned in the drupal site for upgrading drupal from 8 to 9 or (later) [click here for steps](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-to-drupal-9-or-later) but didn't work for me.

Will anyone please help me or provide proper steps to upgrade drupal from 8.9 to 9.3.5?

[image: Click here to see error image]

Answer (score 4):

You should try to get more information about the error.

Add to your settings.php file:

```
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
```

and check the output on your screen again.

You may also try drush to take a look at selecting the option errors from the terminal.

```
drush watchdog:list
```

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this same issue multiple times. If you haven't already done so, try going to /update.php multiple times. (It seems to clear out the update process junk/leftovers and let it work.)

Other than that, it's always some kind of file issue. (I still update manually due to my server setup.) Sometimes it was a folder/sub folder that didn't upload fully or other times it was that some module simply refused to work with the new upgrade until that was updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cache, it worked for me.
In the root of the Drupal run the command
drush cache: rebuild

Answer (score -1):

You have turned off the database. **Please turn it on**

---

Example: **Start MySQL in Xampp
**